# How can I capture video from a webcam in java with an applet?

Tags: java, video, stream, webcam, capture

I am loking into capturing and streaming video over the network using a java applet. So far, it looks like JMF is outdated and FMJ won't be able to capture at any reasonable speed. Is there any other library that I can use to go about capturing and or streaming video from a webcam at at least 10-15 frames per second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this recently and had to write a JNI to capture the video and encode it or decode it.

It is a pain because you have to write the JNI for each platform like Windows 32 and 64 bit, OSX 32 and 64 bit and Linux 32 and 64 bit.

Using JNLP (Java web start) is a better choice than an applet as it allows you to set it up so it will automatically download and install the correct JNI for the current O/S.

Either a JNLP or Applet will require you to generate a signed jar to work.

Comment: In that case I may just use OpenCV for capture.

Comment: Yea you can wrap OpenCV in a JNI if there isn't already a JNI wrapper you could also look at using JNA to call OpenCV directly.